# How to write classpath info to jar by using Ant

Tags: ant

By using Ant, how to write classpath info into the jar. Anyone can show how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write the classpath to the manifest within the jar use the [manifestclasspath](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifestclasspath.html) task.

Take a look at the following question: [Generate manifest class-path from <classpath> in ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858766/generate-manifest-class-path-from-classpath-in-ant) for more details.