# I can't compile and run JAVA code with ant

Tags: java, xml, compilation, ant

I tried different solutions from stackoverflow, but it didn't help. I still have an error which warn me that i have no Main class in my program. Probably i don't know how to properly compile and run files. Error says that could not find app.Main. Make sure you have it in your classpath.

```
<!--Ok -->
<target name="init">

    <property name = "app.bin" value = "bin" />
    <property name = "app.dist" value = "dist" />
    <property name = "app.doc" value = "doc" />
    <property name = "app.log" value = "log" />
    <property name = "app.lib" value = "lib" />
    <property name = "app.src" value = "src" />

        <property name = "p.app" value = "${app.src}/app" />
        <property name = "p.combo" value = "${app.src}/app/ComboBoxMVC" />
        <property name = "p.table" value = "${app.src}/app/TableMVC" />


    <path id="build.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${app.lib}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${app.bin}"/>
    </path>

</target>

<!--Ok -->
<target name ="clean" depends ="init" >

    <delete dir="${app.bin}" />
    <delete dir="${app.doc}" />
    <delete dir="${app.dist}" />

</target>

<!--Ok -->
<target name ="prepare" depends ="clean" >

    <mkdir dir="${app.bin}" />
    <mkdir dir="${app.doc}" />
    <mkdir dir="${app.dist}" />

</target>

<target name="compile" depends="prepare">

    <javac srcdir = "${app.src}"
           destdir = "${app.bin}"
           classpathref="build.classpath">
    </javac>

</target>


<target name = "javadoc" depends = "compile">

    <javadoc destdir = "${app.doc}/Documentation" encoding="UTF-8" classpathref="build.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${app.src}"/>
    </javadoc>

</target>



<target name="jar" depends="javadoc">



</target>



<target name = "run" depends = "jar">

    <java classname="app.Main" classpathref="build.classpath"/>

</target>
```

Structure of my project
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858766/generate-manifest-class-path-from-classpath-in-ant