# execute class in jar file with ant

Tags: ant

I have a jar with the following structure

```
com
   merc
      test.class
lib
   xyz.jar
applicationContext.xml
```

test.class uses xyz.jar. Using ant java task, how do i include the lib folder in the classpath, so that I can execute test.class

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Did you try as documented [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) (like the snippet below) and if so, did you get any error?

```
<java classname="com.merc.test">
     <classpath>
         <pathelement location="lib/xyz.jar"/>
     </classpath>
</java>
```

Comment: my classpath needs to have the jar file that contains com.merc.test, if there is a way to specify lib folder inside say mytest.jar than i can give it a try.

Comment: I guess you need to add a manifest. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682852/apache-ant-manifest-class-path gives some clues on ths.