# adding a external file to a build.xml - java / xml

Tags: java, ant

I have two classes, `ZipComparison` and `Tczip`. `Tczip` digests a `zip` file and processes its `MD5`, while `ZipComparison` searches for `.zip` entries, and compares two different versions of the `.zip` file to determine if they have the same content. For example, in a `package_a` there is `encodes.zip` so I want to determine if in the `package_b` the `encodes.zip` is the same as the `.zip` file in `package_a`. So I process the `MD5`, and if the they match, then I don't need to copy that `MD5`. The `build.xml` is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>

    <path id="external.classpath">
        <pathelement location="src/commons-codec-1.2.jar"/>
    </path>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes" />
        <javac srcdir="src/tczip" destdir="build/classes">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="external.classpath" />
             </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="jar">
        <mkdir dir="build/jar" />
        <jar destfile="build/jar/Tczip.jar" basedir="build/classes">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="tczip.ZipComparison" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run">
        <java jar="build/jar/Tczip.jar" fork="true" />
    </target>

</project>
```

So I'm trying to create an `ant` build file. `ZipComparison` utilizes `Tczip`, but when I compile, the execution is perfect, however, when I do `ant run` I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\souzamor\workspace\tczip>ant run
Buildfile: C:\Users\souzamor\workspace\tczip\build.xml

run:
     [java] Processing: bhmcommonclient.zip
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apach
e/commons/codec/binary/Hex
     [java]     at tczip.Tczip.digest(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at tczip.Tczip.execute(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at tczip.ZipComparison.showFiles(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at tczip.ZipComparison.showFiles(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at tczip.ZipComparison.showFiles(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at tczip.ZipComparison.showFiles(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at tczip.ZipComparison.showFiles(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at tczip.ZipComparison.matchMD5(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at tczip.ZipComparison.main(Unknown Source)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.code
c.binary.Hex
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
     [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
     [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)

     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
     [java]     ... 9 more
     [java] Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 4 seconds
```

I know `Tczip` is missing on the `compile` stage, but how can I add that along `ZipComparison` so I don't have that kind of error ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `tczip.Tczip` class is looking for a class from [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/). Make sure that this jar is on your classpath along with any other dependencies. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/683412/646634) to see how to add the classpath to your JAR's manifest when you create your JAR file from an Ant `<path/>` element.

Also, your XML doesn't use the `depends` tag to make sure that `compile` and `jar` are executed with `run`, and that's not good build script practice. It should really use `depends`:

```
<target name="clean">
    <!-- ... -->
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <!-- ... -->
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <!-- ... -->
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <!-- ... -->
</target>
```